# Incorrect Popup Photo Display with Leaflet css

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

On this link is a very much draft map with photo popups at the orange dots.

https://www.victoriasforestryheritage.org.au/maps/forestlocations/locationtest3/index.html#7/-36.719/146.133

The map is produced from QGIS and with the qgis2web plug in using the Leaflet option.
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/

https://qgis2web-docstests.readthedocs.io/en/testing/

https://leafletjs.com/

The popup should work on hover, which it does. But on first hover the bounding box, if that is the right term, does not expand to surround the photo. With a mouse click it does surround the picture.

Obviously I would like this to come together at hover rather than the process requiring a mouse click after hover.

I have been trying to solve this on the basis that it may be a z-index issue in the leaflet.css file but to no effect. I also thought it may be a maxWidth maxHeight issue but no joy there either.

I obviously need some assistance because my coding knowledge is limited with css and almost non-existent with javascript.

The coding package for the map is available here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1teRbeTRYjBJzaxNeGoi-90wfiFhO-B8e?usp=sharing

and the leaflet.css file with z-index etc is included.

Any advice that points me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Richard